Gas estimation errored - The transaction execution will likely fail. smart contract Eip838ExecutionError: execution reverted
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/callback/IUniswapV3FlashCallback.sol";
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IERC20Minimal.sol";

contract SimpleFlashLoan is IUniswapV3FlashCallback {
    address payable public owner;
    IUniswapV3Pool public pool;

    event FlashLoanInitiated(address indexed initiator, uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1);
    event FlashLoanExecuted(uint256 fee0, uint256 fee1, uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1);
    event FlashLoanFailed(string reason);

    constructor(address _pool) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        pool = IUniswapV3Pool(_pool);
    }

    function startFlashLoan(uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only owner can call this function");
        require(address(pool) != address(0), "Pool address is not set");
        require(amount0 > 0 && amount1 > 0, "Amounts must be greater than zero");

        emit FlashLoanInitiated(msg.sender, amount0, amount1);

        // Increase gas limit when sending transaction
        // Use a higher gas limit than the estimated gas to ensure successful execution
        uint256 gasLimit = gasleft() - 20000; // Adjust as needed

        try pool.flash{gas: gasLimit}(address(this), amount0, amount1, abi.encode(amount0, amount1)) {
            // Flash loan successfully initiated
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            emit FlashLoanFailed(reason);
        } catch {
            emit FlashLoanFailed("Unknown error occurred");
        }
    }

    function uniswapV3FlashCallback(
        uint256 fee0,
        uint256 fee1,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external override {
        require(msg.sender == address(pool), "Invalid sender");

        (uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1) = abi.decode(data, (uint256, uint256));

        emit FlashLoanExecuted(fee0, fee1, amount0, amount1);

        address token0 = pool.token0();
        address token1 = pool.token1();

        try IERC20Minimal(token0).approve(address(pool), amount0 + fee0) {
            IERC20Minimal(token1).approve(address(pool), amount1 + fee1);
            IERC20Minimal(token0).transfer(address(pool), amount0 + fee0);
            IERC20Minimal(token1).transfer(address(pool), amount1 + fee1);
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            emit FlashLoanFailed(reason);
        } catch {
            emit FlashLoanFailed("Unknown error during callback");
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}


At what point are you getting that error? Please add more details.
